# Show Y values inside/above the BarGraphItem itself

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I have the following code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 500)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        widget = QWidget()

        plot = pg.plot()
        y1 = [5, 5, 7, 10, 3, 8, 9, 1, 6, 2] #These values
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

        bargraph = pg.BarGraphItem(x = x, height = y1, width = 0.6, brush ='g')

        plot.addItem(bargraph)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
 
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Which produces the following result:
[image]

Is there a way to show the value of each column inside or above the bar itself?

Like this example from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72002352/pyqtgraph-how-to-name-bars-in-bargraphitem):

[image]

Thanks in advance!